# Pandas dataframe: from info about time of state change get from when to when state lasted

Tags: python, pandas

Please note that i do not know the proper name for the operation i want to perform and therefore i will try to explain using an example:

I have a dataframe like this:

```
sample_sf = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[101, 104, 112, 120, 120, 134, 202, 215, 222, 255, 258, 272, 290, 294, 294, 305, 305, 307, 504, 520, 527, 538, 557, 557], 
    'status':[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    'opponent_id':[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2,2,2,2,4,4,2,3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6,3, 6, 6, 3,6]})
```

That keeps track of whether a certain opponent sees me or not. `Status = 1` indicates that an opponent of a given id found me, whereas status = 0 indicates that the given opponent lost me. Therefore, the first row of my dataframe indicates, that opponent number 1 found me at time 101. Second row means that 2nd opponent found me at time 104, third row means that opponent 1 lost me at time 112, and 4th round means that opponent number 2 lost me at time 120.

When no opponent sees me I am invisible (state 0) and when at least one opponent sees me, i am visible (state 1). I would like to figure out from when to when i was invisible and from when to when i was visible. Where the last observable status should last until the end of the game (at time = 900). Therefore, i want the following dataframe:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'from':[0, 101, 134, 202, 215, 222,255, 258, 272, 290, 307,504,557], 'to':[100, 133, 201, 214, 221, 254, 257, 271,289,306,503,556,900], 'status':[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,0,1,0, 1,9,1,0]})
```

Which looks like this:

```
from    to  status
0   0   100 0
1   101 133 1
2   134 201 0
3   202 214 1
4   215 221 0
5   222 254 1
6   255 257 0
7   258 271 1
8   272 289 0
9   290 306 1
10  307 503 9
11  504 556 1
12  557 900 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which doesn't use any `for` loops. I believe it should be faster than the other suggestions so far (you'd better do a benchmark). It takes into account that 'opponent_id' is essentially an irrelevant information (see my note at the end).

**Code:**

```
sample_sf = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[101, 104, 112, 120, 120, 134, 202, 215, 222, 255, 258, 272, 290, 294, 294, 305, 305, 307, 504, 520, 527, 538, 557, 557],
    'status':[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    'opponent_id':[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2,2,2,2,4,4,2,3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6,3, 6, 6, 3,6]})

out = sample_sf.copy()
out = out.drop(columns=['opponent_id'])
out.loc[out['status'] == 0, 'status'] = -1
out.loc[:, 'status'] = np.cumsum(out['status'])
out.drop_duplicates('time', inplace=True, keep='last')
out = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0], 'status': [0]}).append(out)
out.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
ind = out.loc[out['status'] == 0].index
ind = np.sort(np.concatenate([ind + 1, ind]))
last_status = out['status'][len(out) - 1]
if last_status == 0:
    ind = ind[:-1]
out = out.iloc[ind]
out.rename(columns={'time': 'from'}, inplace=True)
out.insert(1, "to", out['from'].shift(-1, fill_value=901) - 1)
print(out)
```

It will print a desired output:

```
    from   to  status
0      0  100       0
1    101  133       1
5    134  201       0
6    202  214       1
7    215  221       0
8    222  254       1
9    255  257       0
10   258  271       1
11   272  289       0
12   290  306       1
15   307  503       0
16   504  556       1
20   557  900       0
```

**Explanation:**

- Copy `sample_sf` into `out`.
- Drop the 'opponent_id' column. We don't need it.
- Replace all 0's in 'status' column with -1's.
- Use numpy's `np.cumsum()` to write the cumulative sum into 'status' (that is the sum of all numbers up to certain position. Now in 'status' column we have a number of opponents who can see you at each time.
- Drop all rows with equal time leaving only the last one. The reason for this: if at particular moment in time several events happen, we care only about the final number of opponents watching you.
- Append time 0 with status 0 (you begin invisible) and reset indexing.
- Extract into `ind` indices of rows with status 0 (that is when you become invisible).
- Add to this index list also indices of rows when you become visible (that is next index after each status 0). Sort indices. Now in `ind` we have rows when your condition changes from visible to invisible or vice versa.
- Store the last status in `last_status`. If we ended up invisible, then we have to drop the last index in `ind`, because we have no last transitioning from invisible state to visible.
- Leave only the rows in `ind`.
- Rename the column 'time' into 'from' and add column 'to', which is the same as column 'from', but decreased by one and shifted up by one (the last entry is filled with 900).

**Note:**

This solution works *only* in the case when an opponent cannot consequently lose/find you two times in a row, i.e. such input is forbidden:

```
    time  status  opponent_id
0    101       1            1
1    104       1            2
2    112       1            1
```

(opponent 1 found you two times in a row without losing you). This condition is satisfied in your example. So, I assumed it. If it is not the case, consider other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[101, 104, 112, 120, 120, 134, 202, 215, 222, 255, 258, 272, 290, 294, 294, 305, 305, 307, 504, 520, 527, 538, 557, 557],
    'status':[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    'opponent_id':[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2,2,2,2,4,4,2,3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6,3, 6, 6, 3,6]})

set_time = set()
for i in range(1,7):
    l1 = df[df['opponent_id']==i]['time'].tolist()
    l1.sort()
    #print(i, l1)
    for j, k in zip(l1[::2],l1[1::2]):
        #print(j,k)
        set_time |= set(range(j,k))

times = list(set_time)
times.sort()

l2 = [0, times[0]]
for i, j in zip(times, times[1:]):
    if j-i>1:
        l2 += [i,j]
l2 +=[times[-1], 900]

l3 = []
for n, tup in enumerate(zip(l2,l2[1:])):
    a, b = tup
    if n % 2:
        l3 += [[a,b, n%2]]
    else:
        l3 += [[a+1,b-1,n%2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(l3, columns=['from','to','status'])

# Manual override to adjust for end errors.
df1.at[0, 'from']=0
df1.at[df1.index.max(), 'to']=900
```

**Explanation:**

1. Express the times when you are visible to an opponent as a set.
   e.g. For opponent 1 the times that are visible is `set(range(101, 112))`, similarly for opponent 2 it would be `set(range(104,120))`, `set(range(202,215))`,...
2. Take the union of all these sets (i.e. `set_time`). Set removes duplicates, how convenient! :D
3. Convert `set_time` to a list (i.e. `times`), sort it.
4. The for loop: `for i, j in zip(times, times[1:])` is applied to build a list (`l2`) of times when there is a change in the status from invisible to visible and vice versa. Basically we are not interested in the sequential values in the `times` list.
5. Add 2 entries to the front and back of `l2` to adjust for end errors.
6. The last for loop `for n, tup in enumerate(zip(l2,l2[1:]))` constructs a list of times and status for the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a state to hold the number of opponents with status=1.
It scans the data, while maintaining the state, and issues a new change when the number of opponents seeing 'me' changes from 0 to 1 or vice versa.

```
import pandas as pd


def calculate_visibility(data):
    # Prepare state
    nr_opponents_that_see_me = 0
    prev_change_time_point = 0
    nr_opponents_that_see_me_during_prev_change = 0

    # Scan visibility by maintaining state
    result = list()
    for time_point_idx, time_point in enumerate(data.time):
        # Update visibility counter
        nr_opponents_that_see_me += 1 if data.status[time_point_idx] else -1
        is_last_time_point = time_point_idx == len(data.time) - 1
        is_last_change_in_time_point = is_last_time_point or (data.time[time_point_idx + 1] != time_point)
        
        # Check if visibility changed
        if is_last_change_in_time_point:

            turned_invisible = nr_opponents_that_see_me == 0
            turned_visible = nr_opponents_that_see_me == 1 and nr_opponents_that_see_me_during_prev_change == 0
            if turned_invisible or turned_visible:
                result.append([prev_change_time_point, time_point - 1, 1 if turned_invisible else 0])
                prev_change_time_point = time_point

                # Update prev #opponents that see me
                nr_opponents_that_see_me_during_prev_change = nr_opponents_that_see_me

    result.append([time_point, 900, 0 if (nr_opponents_that_see_me == 0) else 1])
    return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["from", "to", "status"])

sample_sf = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [101, 104, 112, 120, 120, 134, 202, 215, 222, 255, 258, 272, 290, 294, 294, 305, 305, 307, 504, 520, 527, 538, 557, 557],
    'status': [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    'opponent_id': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2,2,2,2,4,4,2,3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6,3, 6, 6, 3,6]})

print(calculate_visibility(sample_sf))
```

This produces the following output:

```
    from   to  status
0      0  100       0
1    101  133       1
2    134  201       0
3    202  214       1
4    215  221       0
5    222  254       1
6    255  257       0
7    258  271       1
8    272  289       0
9    290  306       1
10   307  503       0
11   504  556       1
12   557  900       0
```